# How to locate an assembly which forces binding redirect

Tags: .net, nuget, versioning

Say we have:

- assembly A references assebly NH version 2.0.0.0.
- assembly B references assebly NH version 2.0.0.0.
- assembly C references assebly NH version 1.0.0.0 (accidently)
- our test web project references asseblies A, B, C and NH 2.0.0.0.

Nuget has a great functionality, which automatically detects these assembly conflicts and creates a binding redirect instructions. Nuget command *Add-BindingRedirect* will add such strings to test project web.config file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="NH" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Now imagine that we have much more libraries, referrencing NH.
The question is: what is the best (preferable not manual) way to identify the odd version?

Comment: If you can run your app with the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) enabled for `log all binds`. That should give you information who is loading what and which version.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you should have posted it as an answer I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To investigate binding errors you can utilize the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).

You can configure it to **log all binds** which will basically give you insight in which assemblies gets loaded from where.

typical output looks like this:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = graphicfailtest.resources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = C:\bla\graphic\cs\
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : graphicfailtest, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===

LOG: Processing DEVPATH.
LOG: DEVPATH is not set. Falling through to regular bind.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Post-policy reference: graphicfailtest.resources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:..../graphicfailtest.resources.DLL.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```